# Connect multiple source pins together to power signal in Eaglesoft

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, high-current

1. According to PCB shown below, I have a bunch of MOSFETs with HSOF package with 7 pins of source for each and failed to connect EVERY pin to the connector. In other words, when routing the source signal to their destination which is the connector, only ***one*** of the pins connects and the others were left unrouted.
2. The other question is when drawing a polygon with the same signal name, the connection between polygon and DIP pin is too weak to carry high current signals. Is there any option in Eaglesoft to make these kinds of connections strong enough for high current purposes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To avoid having unrouted connections, make sure pins/pads are connected in the schematic view. The PCB design view will show unrouted connections as lines. Polygons are just the perimeter definition for a solid copper area. Search for "PCB trace width calculator" to find tools to help you calculate how wide a trace should be based on current, copper thickness, temperature rise, etc. Your polygon needs to meet the minimum width derived from that calculation. Add the relevant portion of your schematic, component values, and specify how much current is "high current" for better answers.

Comment: Are all the pins connected in the schematic and/or library device?

Comment: It looks like pin2 is connected to the large circle with a thin trace, and then 2-3-4-5-6-7-8 are connected with wider traces. DId you want them all connected to the large circle independently?

Comment: @JYelton thank you I will consider these

Comment: @TomCarpenter yes all of them is connected properly in the schematic

Comment: @CrossRoads yes, the pin number 2 of each mosfets is Gate, so for best performance and lower the chance of accidentally powering on the mosfets, it's better to make the gate traces as similar as possible ( I mean the width and lengths )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answering question 1 :
The problem was on the library. In the symbol there was 7 different pins which was not connected to each other, so the problem was solved by removing them and placing 1 source pin instead of 7 and appending the pins all together in device page.
For question 2 :
Simply right-click on polygons and select properties, then uncheck the thermal and OK, all the pins will be merging with polygons.